# How are remastered games handled on Arqade?

Tags: discussion

There are quite a few remasters hitting lately; Bioshock, Skyrim, etc. Are we going to use the same tags for these games? Or will there be a new tag for the remasters? Will it depend largely from game to game?

Comment: Does anything in the gameplay actually change?

Comment: @Ash That's what I'm getting at.

Comment: that's not clear from your question.

Comment: @Ash "Will it depend largely from game to game?" should cover it, I think. At least that's what I meant by that question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is one of those things that will be decided on a case-by-case basis. While many remasters simply add new graphics to an old game, they also often add bugfixes, and sometimes entire new features.